# Wordpress Site coded in php, Google bot unable to crawl

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, web-crawler

My forums is coded in PHP, its a Wordpress website. My forum pages are using URL parameter to fetch data to fill the template. Already tried rewriting but failed.

Things to know

```
Url : http://www.studplex.com/forum-topic/?discussion_id=22
```

Tried to rewrite in to : failed

```
forum-topic/discussion_id/22/
```

Error Message in bing webmaster

[image: http://goo.gl/XmPKBT]

If anyone give some suggestion

Comment: Google typically crawls by following links on your site to posts such as that. Do you have any such links? Also, check for a robots.txt file that might be limiting your crawling

Comment: already checked robots.txt its not creating any issue the above snapshot shows http code unknown and size is 0. so how can i resolve this as search engine will never rank my forum pages

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `Allow: /` right after `User-agent: *` to your *robots.txt* file.